# Wrong value when minus 2 date

Tags: php

I get the wrong value when I subtract two dates.
This is my code:

```
$date2=strtotime('01-08-2014');
$date1=strtotime('28-06-2014');
$diff=$date2-$date1;
```

Output:

```
$diff=-27
```

EDIT :

```
$date2 should be --> date('d/m/Y',strtotime('01-08-2014'));
$date1 should be --> date('d/m/Y',strtotime('28-06-2014'));
```

Can anyone solve my problem?

thanks

Comment: What is `$date` defined as?

Comment: Should be `$date1` & not `$date`.

Comment: It doesnt. When i test it, i get an output of `2937600` which is probably correct. You need to show us more code. The error must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('01-08-2014');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('28-06-2014');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
```

Comment: i got this ,after echo"$interval"; --> Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string

Comment: you can echo $interval its an object u can print_r() and see the values and get the values as $interval->m, $interval->d etc. Check the manual how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
 $diff=$date2-$date;
```

to

```
   $diff=$date2-$date1;
```

Comment: no, it's just my wrong type when type this question

Comment: @user2924643 , the code should work, please see link https://eval.in/129231

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$daylen = 60*60*24;

   $date1 = '2010-03-29';
   $date2 = '2009-07-16';

   echo (strtotime($date1)-strtotime($date2))/$daylen;

?>
```